# How to emulate scanf in dart?

Tags: dart, scanf

How to emulate scanf in dart?

I want to translate the following C code into dart.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    double a,b;
    printf("a b? ");
    scanf("%lf%lf",&a,&b);
    printf("a=%lf b=%lf\n",a,b);
}
```

As I know, I cannot use call by reference, variable number arguments function call or destructuring assignment in dart.
So, it seems that it is impossible to make a function emulating scanf for now.

Here is my version in dart.

```
import "dart:io";
void main() {
  stdout.write("a b? ");
  var line = stdin.readLineSync();
  var tokens = line?.split(RegExp(r'\s+'));
  double a = double.tryParse(tokens?[0] ?? '0') ?? 0;
  double b = double.tryParse(tokens?[1] ?? '0') ?? 0;
  print("a=$a b=$b");
}
```

In there any possible improvement in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version using Iterator.

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  stdout.write("a b? ");
  var scan = Scan();
  var a = scan.getDouble();
  var b = scan.getInt();
  print("a=$a b=$b");
}

class Scan {
  Iterator? it;

  Scan([String? line]) {
    it = (line ?? stdin.readLineSync())?.split(RegExp(r'\s+')).iterator;
  }

  double getDouble() {
    return double.tryParse(it?.moveNext() == true ? it?.current : '') ?? 0;
  }

  int getInt() {
    return int.tryParse(it?.moveNext() == true ? it?.current : '') ?? 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative version for dart 3.0 and above

```
import 'dart:io';

List scanf(String fmt) {
  var line = stdin.readLineSync();
  final in_it = line?.split(RegExp(r'\s+')).iterator;
  List res = [];
  for (final match in RegExp(r'%(\w+)').allMatches(fmt)) {
    if (in_it!.moveNext()) {
      String v = in_it.current;
      switch (match[1]) {
        case 's':
          res.add(v);
        case 'd' || 'i' || 'l':
          res.add(int.tryParse(v) ?? 0);
        case 'f' || 'lf' || 'g':
          res.add(double.tryParse(v) ?? 0.0);
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}

void main() {
  double a;
  int b;
  stdout.write("a b? ");
  [a] = scanf("%f");
  [b] = scanf("%d");
  print("a=$a b=$b");
}
```